# Performance of MKL `dgesvd` vs MKL `LAPACKE_dgesvd`?

Tags: c, performance, matrix, linear-algebra, intel-mkl

`dgesvd` seems to be a `LAPACKE_dgesvd` with the layout `LAPACK_COL_MAJOR`, but looking at the examples for [`dgesvd`](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dgesvd_ex.c.htm) and [`LAPACKE_dgesvd`](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/lapacke_dgesvd_col.c.htm) it seems there is an extra step in the `dgesvd` example where an optimal workspace is queried and allocated.

1. Is it correct to assume that this step is to figure out if the input matrix is `COL_MAJOR` or `ROW_MAJOR`?
2. Is it correct to assume that once the optimal workspace is figured out, 'dgesvd' internally calls `LAPACKE_dgesvd` with the appropriate layout?
3. If I already know the matrix layout to be `COL_MAJOR` is using `LAPACKE_dgesvd` better (faster/less expensive) than `dgesvd`?

Answer (score 1):

We have two functions here which refer to two different interfaces:

```
i.  dgesvd         : calls fortran interface
ii. LAPACKE_dgesvd : calls C interface
```

For detail [see this](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/_gesvd.htm).

1. No it is not correct. As you will notice in the first call to `dgesvd` the value of `lwork` is set to `-1` which [as documented here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/469236) is used for just calculating the size of `lwork`. So if you already know about the size of `lwork` you don't need to call it twice. Input matrix has to be `LAPACK_COL_MAJOR` for `dgesvd` as this is default for fortran. Also there is no way to calculate if the matrix is row major or column major.
2. No it's not true. `dgesvd` is the `fortran` interface which was implemented first.
3. This would depend on the compiler optimization. If the matrix is small it probably wouldn't matter. For me if its column major I would use fortran interface.

For matrix layout infotmation [see this](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/cinterface.htm#matrixlayout). Here is the [technical paper for C interface](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/C_Interface_to_LAPACK.pdf)